# How can I call angular ngresources $cancelRequest gracefully without it invoking the error callback?

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular application the user can return to a previous screen (which is just hiding the current screen).  The user may do this in the middle of a long running AJAX request.  I'd like to cancel the Ajax request behind the scenes if this happens.

I can get ngresource's $cancelRequest to work, but it causes the error callback to be thrown.  Is there a way to make that not happen or to distinguish a $cancelRequest from say a failed communication with the server?  Thanks in advance.

Plunk (has some additional UI to it): http://plnkr.co/edit/tYj4FRQ9EaCTH4iW9PcL?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);

app.service("Photos", function($resource) {
  return $resource(null, {}, {
    getPhotos: {
      url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
      method: "GET",
      isArray: true,
      cancellable: true
    }
  });
});

MyController.$inject = ["$log", "$timeout", "Photos"];

function MyController($log, $timeout, Photos) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.message = "Test message";
  vm.result = null;
  vm.photosRequest = null;

  vm.$onInit = function() {
    vm.message = "Test message";
    vm.photosRequest = Photos.getPhotos({},
      function(response) {
        vm.callbackHit = "Good Callback Hit";
        vm.result = response;
      },
      function(response) {
        vm.callbackHit = "Bad Callback Hit (Don't want to see this if $cancelRequest was called, but do if there was an error talking to the server.)"
        vm.result = response;
      }
    );
  };

  // Simulating a cancel request.  How can I tell the error was a cancel and handle differently in the error callback?
  $timeout(function() {
    $log.info("cancelling request");
    vm.photosRequest.$cancelRequest();
  }, 25);
}

app.component("myComponent", {
  templateUrl: "myComponent.html",
  require: {},
  bindings: {},
  controller: MyController,
  controllerAs: "vm"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/NR9oyXQ8FMdouVAC1Hqx?p=preview

Created an additional property to keep track of your request:

```
var vm = this;
vm.message = "Test message";
vm.result = null;
vm.photosRequest = null;
// keep track of request state to avoid race conditions
vm.currentRequest = {id: 0, cancelled: false};
```

When you cancel the request, you update the state.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $log.info("cancelling request");
  vm.photosRequest.$cancelRequest();
  vm.currentRequest.cancelled = true;
}, 25);
```

And in your callbacks, you check the state when deciding what to do:

```
vm.photosRequest = Photos.getPhotos({},
  response => {
    if (vm.currentRequest.id == requestNumber) { // ignore old requests resolving late
      vm.callbackHit = "Good Callback Hit";
      vm.result = response;
    }
  }, error => {
    if (vm.currentRequest.id == requestNumber) { // ignore old requests resolving late
      if (vm.currentRequest.cancelled) { // fail silently
        $log.info('doing nothing in response to cancelled request');
      } else {
        vm.callbackHit = "Bad Callback Hit (Don't want to see this if $cancelRequest was called, but do if there was an error talking to the server.)"
        vm.result = error;
      }
    }
  });
```

Every time that you make a new request, you reset the state.

```
var requestNumber = ++vm.currentRequest.id;
vm.currentRequest.cancelled = false; // reset cancelled state on new request
vm.photosRequest = Photos.getPhotos({},...)
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but the request state doesn't seem to keep track if $cancelRequest is called or not, so you have to keep track yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought about this, but was hoping there was a better way to avoid it.  I'll mark this as the answer, unless someone presents something better in the next week.  Only thing I changed was swapping the order of these lines: vm.photosRequest.$cancelRequest();
  vm.currentRequest.cancelled = true;  so that vm.currentRequest.cancelled  = true; comes before.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I would love to hear of a better solution, too. I also realized that it might be prudent to cancel a request before making a new request, so you would have something like
`vm.photosRequest.$cancelRequest(); vm.photosRequest = Photos.getPhotos({},...);` whenever you make a new request.